# Screen scraping with Selenium in Python: links constructed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I'm building a webcrawler using Selenium and Python and I've run into a bit of a snag. The crawler works by finding all the links using

`ListlinkerHref = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")`

and iterating over ListlinkerHref. This works great for classic links with an href attribute. However, a quick look at the source code for the homepage of www.primitiveworldproductions.com between lines 110 and 135 (approximately) shows a bunch of links built using Javascript with no href attributes in sight.

I know next to nothing about Javascript and I looked through the Selenium docs, but I can't find a way to detect those links. Is there a robust, all-encompassing way to find all links in the source code, including those constructed by Javascript without href attributes? Note that my crawler doesn't work by clicking on links (it just adds them to a list to be opened later) and the crawler needs to be able to crawl any site, without regard to the specifics. Is this possible?

EDIT:

Here are the first few lines from the part of the source code in question.

```
var n111 = menuMgr.createMenu("ref111");

n111.addItem("126", "Staff Bios", "/staff.aspx", ["systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif","systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif"], true, null, "ref126");

var n112 = menuMgr.createMenu("ref112");

n112.addItem("146", "Promotional Video", "/PromotionalVideo.aspx", ["systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif","systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif"], true, null, "ref146");

n112.addItem("120", "Video for Social Media", "/vsm.aspx", ["systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif","systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif"], true, null, "ref120");

n112.addItem("147", "Live Webcasting and Event Video", "/Webcasting.aspx", ["systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif","systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif"], true, null, "ref147");
```

Comment: Can you copy paste whats "between 110 and 135 (approximately) "

Comment: Here's one. They're all variations on the exact same theme. (I'm only including one here because otherwise it looks like hell.)

n112.addItem("148", "Educational Programming ", "/Educational.aspx", ["systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif","systems/nlsmenu/img/submenuovr.gif"], true, null, "ref148");


EDIT: Context might help: Basically it's constructing a nav menu and adding items to it. Above is one of the items.

Answer (score 0):

If you click with right-button of the mouse on any item in the menu and then choose "inspect element" you'll see HTML code that was generated with JavaScript. You'll see that menu items on  primitiveworldproductions.com have no href attribute and the link's target loads on the onclick event. I am afraid there is no simple method to extract links from this menu.